# Can you crack a pipe by freezing the faucet or does it require a water volume between ice slug and closed pipe?

Tags: ice

My understanding of a winter freeze breaking a pipe is that if you get an ice slug "somewhere" a few feet or more upstream of a closed faucet then any subsequent freezing will cause a pressure increase because of water expansion and that cracks the pipe.

So what happens if you have a vertical pipe and make the top of the pipe colder and colder, so that it freezes (e.g. think exterior faucet) and the slug of ice grows steadily down the pipe.

As far as I can tell, this should at worst just slightly increase pressure back at the pump station, i.e. completely no issue. When the hard-freeze is over then, presumably the house is warmer than the outside, so the ice will rescind back up the pipe and finally release the faucet. No pressure build up.

So why do people take care to thermally insulate exterior faucets?

Comment: It requires no large air pockets to compress. Water freezes, the ice is less dense (so expands) and with no other give in the system the pipes may burst.

Comment: The "give" in the system is the essentially infinite volume of water on the line back to the pumping station. The ice at the top will freeze and the expansion which push the water down as the ice will float above and then every around the faucet is seized up. Once any ice is formed, then that ice will no longer expand (density of ice at 0C is 0.92 g/cc which actually increases slightly to 0.93 at -180C). And that all repeats the whole way down the pipe. As long at there is a temperature gradient along the pipe (coldest at the top), then I don't see where pressure can build up.